# what to validate when saving user ckeditor html data into a database

Tags: mysql, html, asp.net-mvc, post, ckeditor

i have a textarea and I [am using ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) to allow users to enter data and click upload.  This will save the html of this data to a mysql database table to display on a separate web page

What do i need to worry about in terms of what people are posting.  Do i need to add any validation on the front end or back end to ensure that they are not posting dangerous scripts, etc . .

What is the easiest way to validate that what is being posted is fine to store and put back to the client to display later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i need to add any validation on the front end or back end to ensure
>   that they are not posting dangerous scripts, etc

No, you shouldn't worry about this. As far as you use parametrized queries in order to store data to avoid SQL injection a relational database doesn't care much about what kind of text you are throwing at it.

Problems might arise when you try to display this data back on a web page. It is at this moment that you should ensure that it is properly HTML encoded.

For razor:

```
@...
```

For WebForms (ASP.NET 4.0)

```
<%: ...
```

For WebForms (prior to ASP.NET 4.0)

```
<%= Html.Encode(...
```

Or for all of the above:

```
Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomePropertyOftheViewModel)
```

> What is the easiest way to validate that what is being posted is fine
>   to store and put back to the client to display later.

Parametrized queries to store data (only if you are using a relational database) and HTML encode to display back.

You might also find the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx) useful about the [Microsoft Anti-Xss library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know ckeditor do not supply any build in xss protection (you should always verify such things on server side). In addition to Darin Dimitrov answer I can say that in my recent project I need to display user input as html, and do not encode it. If you face similar situation (and you almost definitelly are - usually there is no point of using ckeditor and ignore format) - look at:
http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html 
If this is your case - just sanitize html using Sanitize method from the post and then you can display it as it is.